# How to add an exception to the @requestmapping in java?

Tags: java, rest, api, request, request-mapping

I have the following request

```
@RequestMapping("/**/")
```

and I also have a request in another class

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
```

but it seems that even when `/home` gets called the `//` always runs as well. Is there a way to have an exception in the `//` saying like all files but `/home`?

Thanks

Comment: That's odd, it should only call one (the most specific match). Maybe `/home` is raising an exception and `/**/` is getting called during the error flow? Or an include? Are you testing this in a browser? It could be trying to load a favicon.

Comment: I should have also mentioned that one class is a Controller and the other is RestController. So does that mean that it won't be the most specific match it'll run both of them if the path matches at all? @teppic